# Creating a Ticket in remedy Using Python pyARS

Tags: python, python-2.7, remedy

I need help creating a python pyARS class to submit tickets to BMC Remedy's Helpdesk product.

Wondering if anyone has done this already and is willing to share either code, or experience.
Thanks in Advance.

Background of what I have:

I have a gui that the user files out and that creates a ticket based off the information the user submits.